# Having wrong parameter order for glAttachShader but position drawn correctly

Tags: opengl

I have 2 shaders: vertex shader and fragment shader

vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   color = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
}
```

when I was using glAttachShader I passed in the parameters in the order (shader,program) and somehow the vertex was drawn correctly but color was wrong.

Just wondering why the position was correct even though I passed in the parameters in the wrong order? Thanks

Comment: I would guess that the shader program handle and the vertex shader handle had the same value. Especially if this program was the first one created, it is very likely that this happens.

Comment: Perhaps the IDs were the same? you could print their `int` value and compare.

Comment: the IDs were 1,2,3, all different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a compatibility profile context. If that's the case, your shader program was not used at all, and you were rendering with the fixed pipeline. This explains the wrong color for your rendering.

If you used `glGetError()`, you would have noticed that `glAttachShader()` generated an error, as well as subsequent program related calls like `glLinkProgram()` and `glUseProgram()`. Since `glUseProgram()` failed, you were still using the fixed pipeline.

With a core profile context, I would not expect you to see any rendering, since having a valid program is required. Even though the outcome is implementation dependent. Rendering without a program is not an error. The core profile spec says (emphasis added):

> The current program for a stage is considered active if it contains executable code for that stage; otherwise, no program is considered active for that stage. If there is no active program for the vertex or fragment shader stages, the results of vertex and/or fragment processing **will be undeﬁned**.